# Enabling a Kiosk App on a Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I am currently developing a kiosk application and have been trying to use the "Manage kiosk applications..." option in the Chrome://extensions page when developer mode is on.

Whenever I choose an application in the manage kiosk applications popup it just saying invalid application. I've tried local IDs, Chrome Web Store IDs and still nothing works.

In the manifest I've allowed kiosk mode and have another version with kiosk only enabled but that still doesn't work.

This is not a hosted app, all the assets are local and the Chromebook is not managed.

I've tried other solutions such as logging out and pressing ctrl+alt+k at login. I've wiped the chromebook and restarted fresh.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not hosting the app in the Chrome Web Store, Managing Kiosk Applications should be done by entering the `app ID` and the `URL` of the third-party web server in the **Specify a Custom App** dialog and click **Add**.

You may check [Create a Chrome Kiosk App](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3316168?hl=en) to know more details on how to create, publish and add the app as kiosk app.

Answer (score 0):

Kiosk apps can only be installed from the "Manage kiosk applications..." menu if they are published in the Chrome Web Store as either "Public" or "Unlisted".  If the app is published as "Private" it will fail to load.